# Set the selectedIndex property and selectedItems is empty

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, selectedindex

I have an wpf application that use the MVVM with a datagrid. I set the selectedIndex property in the viewModel, but the SelectedItems property is empty. Shouldn't it have the selected the selected item?

Comment: It should - so you are probably doing something wrong. You should show some code, otherwise it's pretty hard to help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily.

One way of doing this is to set SelectedItem property in the datagrid xaml to a property on your view model which implements INotifyPropertyChanged. 
Then set the xaml binding mode to two way.

Then if you click on a selected item it will trigger a change from the xaml binding to update the value in the view model